# Was this line from 24 scripted?

Tags: 24

In S4 E9 around 22:46 (streaming), Jack is speaking with Tony about how Dina and Behrooz Araz do not show up on any watch lists. At that moment, Erin Driscoll calls Jack.

> **Jack**
> Yeah?
> **Erin**
> Jack, it's Driscoll. Homeland Security...
> **Jack**
> Hold on, Erin. I can barely hear ya. (Walks outdoors with Tony).
> Go ahead.

We know that phone calls occurred in real-time. Something felt off about the way Jack asked Erin to wait. I'm curious, does anyone know if this was scripted or there was actually bad cell service?

Comment: I seriously doubt they were actually making a call and there would have been bad signal. In fact, I seem to remember in a 24 "making of" feature that they said there were so many phone conversations on the show they always had both actors involved in the call in the studio reading the lines, so they could react properly. I suspect in some productions there's just no one there and the person on the phone just speaks their half of the conversation, or the "remote end" is read by someone on set such as the director or someone.

Comment: 24 let Sutherland practise his *pièce de résistance*, telephone acting 101… over & over & over again;) 'Phone rings: answer whilst dropping voice an octave. Look up to your left, pause, look down, pause, look straight ahead, pause, look high left again. Hang up right in the middle of a sent…' He was still doing it in Designated Survivor, 15 years later. [& I agree with Darren. It was scripted, no doubt.] 24 was a panicky production, often filming only a month before air, but it was tight & well-controlled.

Answer (score 3):

24 was not actually *filmed* in real time, it was just set to *run* in real time.  Thus, there were no actual calls made, it was merely acting with a phone as a prop.  It's conceivable that the two sides of the phone call weren't even filmed on the same *day*, since any delays in shooting could adversely effect the natural light and cause continuity issues, and trying to coordinate two actors would lead to twice as many possibilities of lines being screwed up than just having one actor handle their lines.

Comment: +1 - I hadn't ever even considered anyone would think it was actually filmed in real time… that would be quite some feat;))

Comment: @Tetsujin Now I feel like there should be a "24" Documentary series that has to film things about the making of 24 in real time...and the camera crew and director must sign a weavor that they can't go to the bathroom the whole darn time! ;)

Comment: Just fix it in post. [Liam Neeson Calls Mr. Rooney](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hN6h0ZWdrWA)